# How to update trained Naive Bayes model saved with joblib

Tags: python, machine-learning, text-classification, naivebayes

I am trying to update my already trained model so that it can correct the errors it is making. For that, I am partially fitting the new data for which it was giving incorrect labels with the new correct labels

I have saved my Bayesian model in a file like this:

```
model1 = MultinomialNB()                    #NaiveBayes model
model1.partial_fit(features_matrix, label_matrix, [0,1,2])
filename = 'trained_NBmodel.pkl'              #saving the trained model
joblib.dump(model1, filename)
```

and then loading it another file like this:

```
loaded_model = joblib.load('trained_NBmodel.pkl')
loaded_model.partial_fit(new_features_matrix, new_label_matrix)
filename = 'trained_NBmodel.pkl'              #saving the trained model
joblib.dump(loaded_model, filename)
```

now it should use the updated model and if new_features_matrix is given to predict, it should predict new_label_matrix with high accuracy but the model is not. It gives the same label matrix as it was giving before refitting. Could it be that I have trained my initial model with similar data many times with different labels that it is not able to learn from fewer data?

Comment: you get an error, or just less good results than expected? If the second is true, is it the same result as without the second fit or does it differ?

Comment: I have updated the question, please see it now

Comment: try to change the first part of code to `features_matrix.append.(new_features_matrix)` ,  `label_matrix.append(new_label_matrix)` , `model1.partial_fit(features_matrix, label_matrix, [0,1,2])` . and see if you get the same result.

Comment: I don't want to do that, I have built a model on existing data and want to improve the model with new data. Storing the previous feature matrices is not efficient. I can always train a new model with the combined data. Isn't there any other way?

Comment: You want to identify the problem. If you do what I told you the result will either be the same as before and therefore you have to look into your data or the result will change and you have to look in your code. Without knowing your data and how you 'preprocess' it  its hard to tell where the problem is here.